# Automating firefox extension

Tags: firefox, automation, firefox-addon

I am trying to automate safari and firefox browsers under Mac OS X. I am currently using AppleScript to automate Safari Browser. I have a specific extension written for both Safari and Firefox.

I can do automation on my extension using applescript on safari browser. Since Safari is Native Cocoa based, using applescript is like butter. But i have no idea on how to automate firefox extensions. Remember, i am not automating WebPages. I am trying to automate the extension alone.

Please suggest me any free tool to automate firefox extensions.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/

iMacros fireefox addon is pretty good try it out